# Getting web page title from setWebViewClient?

Tags: java, android

i am using webview in my android app.
i want to get title of current page shown in webview.
i am using following code to do that

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title); 
        t.setText(view.getTitle());
    }
}
```

This code works but not always.
Sometimes it doesn't show the title.
sometimes it shows title of previous page.
Whats wrong here??

Comment: try to check before Textview Settext view.getTitle() is empty! or call load url after check view.getTitle()!

Comment: Call it after `loadUrl` and check.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. The previous page only shown for me.

Answer (score 7):

The `WebChromeClient` will give you the web page title faster than the `WebViewClient`

```
webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String sTitle) {
        super.onReceivedTitle(view, sTitle);
        if (sTitle != null && sTitle.length() > 0) {
            title.setText(sTitle);
        } else {
            title.setText("Web Page");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this code, am getting web page title

```
webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String name = webview.getTitle();
        Log.v("Title",name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     sugg@ : don't put frequently updating things in Toast, it takes 2 seconds to update.

Comment: When i use it and browse 4-5 pages i get title of previous page.

Comment: @Praveenkumar Likely because `onPageFinished` is called multiple times like `shouldInterceptRequest`